# mmap error in centos

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am new to kakfa tool. I tried Kafka with ssl.when I tried to run the producer it throws the following error.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: 
os::commit_memory(0x000000072cd00000, 353370112, 0) failed; error='Cannot 
allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 353370112 bytes for committing 
reserved memory.
```

This is my producer script

```
  /usr/hdf/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list node1.kafka.prod.tt-dp.com:6668 --topic prodtest4 –security-protocol SSL
```

Environment - centos (AWS)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It will be difficult to help you without the broker properties file, the JVM flags used to run Kafka and some details on the machine or VM you are using.